# Speech synthesis not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, speech-recognition, screen-readers, speech-synthesis

What i am trying to achieve here is the HTML Accessibility functionality. I want a single API like speechsynthesis which will work in all the browsers. Speechsynthesis doesn't work for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done purely client side cross browser. However, there are JavaScript libraries that abstract both browser native functionality when it's available or call a web service api to get the audio otherwise.

https://responsivevoice.org/ is an example of this.

Comment: Yes. I have been working on this lately. But this seems to be a paid service for commercial use. Anyways thanks for the validation.

Comment: @VivekSingh Could you mark my answer as correct if you are happy with it please?