# Internet Explorer Browser : TextAudio() Method is not defined Error & 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance' is undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Text to Speech</h2>
    <div><input type="text" id="text-to-speech" placeholder="Enter text to speak..."/></div>
    <div><button type="button" onclick="textToAudio()">Speak</button></div>
    <br/>
    <div><small><b>NOTE:</b> Enter text and click on speak button.</small></div>
    <script>
        /* JS comes here */
        function textToAudio() {
            let msg = document.getElementById("text-to-speech").innerHTML;
            
            let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            speech.lang = "en";
            
            speech.text = msg;
            speech.volume = 1;
            speech.rate = 1;
            speech.pitch = 1;
            
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Working on Chrome and Firefox but Not working in IE browser , I think IE is not support feature of SpeechSynthesisUtterance.
-> Got Error Like , this method is textToAudio() undefined...
Can any one suggest me , what can I do so that It's support all browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speech synthesis not working for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036529/speech-synthesis-not-working-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: Yes, it's not implemented in IE, WebView Android and Opera Android browsers (maybe few others not so big browsers)

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

[SpeechSynthesisUtterance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance#browser_compatibility) is not supported by IE. In IE, we can only use Microsoft [SpVoice Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723602(v=vs.85)). In the code, we need to detect the browser version first, if IE then use `SpVoice`, if other browsers then use `SpeechSynthesisUtterance`. Please refer to the cross-browser code below:

```js
function textToAudio() {
  let msg = document.getElementById("text-to-speech").value;

  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If IE 11
  {
    var voiceObj = new ActiveXObject("Sapi.SpVoice");
    voiceObj.Speak(msg);
  } 
  else // If another browser
  {
    let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    speech.lang = "en";
    speech.text = msg;
    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Text to Speech</h2>
<div><input type="text" id="text-to-speech" placeholder="Enter text to speak..." /></div>
<div><button type="button" onclick="textToAudio()">Speak</button></div>
<br />
<div><small><b>NOTE:</b> Enter text and click on speak button.</small></div>
```

Please pay attention that you need to enable ActiveX under **Internet Options> Security> Internet> Custom level...** in IE to make `SpVoice` work. You can refer to my setting below:

[image]